# Yeoman + angularjs + restify

Tags: node.js, yeoman, restify

I've written an API using **restify**. Now I'm developing a webapp with **angular**, using **yeoman** workflow.

I can run two servers, one for restify "localhost:3000" and one for the ui "localhost:3001".

But I need only one server, better if managed by yeoman. I guess it's possible to put a "proxy" which redirect all requests to localhost:3001/api to localhost:3000/api, but having only one server is preferable.

Answer (score 2):

I got it working adding a new task to `Gruntfile.js`:

```
  grunt.registerTask('server', 'Start a custom web server.', function() {
    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'bower-install',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'watch'
    ]);
    var server = require('./app.js');
    server.use(require('connect-livereload')({
      port: 35729
    }));
    server.get(/^\/.*$/, require('restify').serveStatic({
        'directory' : 'app',
        'default' : 'index.html'
    }));
    server.listen(9000);
  });
```

`app.js` is where restify is initialized, I had to add this line at the end:

```
module.exports = server;
```

Comment: is this really working for you?  On my side, `connect-livereload` and other connect middelware is not working with Restify, which claims to have no intent of supporting connect middleware.

Comment: it was more than an year ago. I remember it worked, but maybe that version of restify had connect middleware support.